# Why I keep getting query logs for elements in list after using joinedload in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following models:

```py
import logging

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import orm, event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine


logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger("for-god-sake")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


web_app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(web_app)


@event.listens_for(Engine, "before_cursor_execute")
def before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, parameters, context, executemany):
    logger.debug("Start Query: %s", statement)


class Car(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class Pieces(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pieces'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    car_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cars.id'))
    display_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    pieces_specs = db.relationship('PieceSpec')

    @classmethod
    def full_load_with_specs(cls, car_id):
        return cls.query.options(orm.joinedload(cls.pieces_specs, innerjoin=True)).filter_by(car_id=car_id).order_by(text('display_id'))


class PieceSpec(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pieces_specs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    car_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cars.id'))
    piece_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pieces.id'), nullable=False)
    value = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

When I call `pieces_list = Pieces.full_load_with_specs(123)` the query printed in debug is:

```sql
SELECT pieces.id AS pieces_id, pieces.car_id AS pieces_car_id, pieces.display_id AS pieces_display_id, pieces_specs_1.id AS pieces_specs_1_id, pieces_specs_1.car_id AS pieces_specs_1_car_id, pieces_specs_1.piece_id AS pieces_specs_1_piece_id, pieces_specs_1.value AS pieces_specs_1_value 
FROM pieces JOIN pieces_specs AS pieces_specs_1 ON pieces.id = pieces_specs_1.piece_id 
WHERE pieces.car_id = %(car_id_1)s ORDER BY display_id
```

Which I assume is right. Then, in this for:

```py
pieces_list = Pieces.full_load_with_specs(123)
for piece in pieces_list:
    for piece_spec in piece.pieces_specs:
        logger.debug(piece_spec.value)
```

For the first iterate, I got the logger for the `piece_spec.value` without a query as expected, but for the other pieces, I started get queries log for the others specs like this:

```sql
SELECT pieces_specs.id AS pieces_specs_id, pieces_specs.car_id AS pieces_specs_car_id, pieces_specs.piece_id AS pieces_specs_piece_id, pieces_specs.value AS pieces_specs_value 
FROM pieces_specs 
WHERE pieces_specs.id = %(param_1)s
```

So why `before_cursor_execute` had been called for a piece_spec after the first iteration in `pieces_lists`? I assume that because SQLAlchemy are executing the query in database but it should not, right? What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using:

```
Flask==1.1.4
SQLAlchemy==1.3.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
```

Ty All!!!